# Not all code paths return a value (bools)

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm in the process of creating a messaging service application for experience. However, I've stumbled across an error I've encountered before. Here is my method:

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

        foreach (string fileName in files)
        {
            if (fileName == pcName)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this method returns a yes or no answer on if the user's txt file exists in the folder. Now, to me, all code paths return a value. It makes sense, obviously the compiler doesn't think the same because I get an error on "bool userExists" complaining that not all code paths return a value. How can I fix this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Prefer `EnumerateFiles` to `GetFiles`, see my answer.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to check just the first file, whatever it may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if for example, the list files is empty?
The compiler reach the end of the function without hitting a return statement, that's what it tells you.

The good way to write your code is:

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

    foreach (string fileName in files)
    {
        if (fileName == pcName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And it could be the moment to become familiar with Linq:

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(usersFile)
                    .Any(file => file == pcName);
}
```

Comment: `.Where(file => file == pcName).Any()` - facepalm, really. Why not to use `Any(file => file == pcName)`?

Comment: I found that Linq is already hard to read. It makes more sense to filter, then test for existence, it cut the logic, and the performance is equivalent. The operator Any(predicate) do too much in one for me :) FYI, I do the same for First, Last, Count... I always use a predicate with the Where.

Comment: Linq is hard to read, because some people use two methods instead single overload, which is intended for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

What if the `files` was empty? so you can do this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

foreach (string fileName in files)
{
    if (fileName == pcName)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Comment: you mean, what if `files` was empty. if `files` is null the code will fail with a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It doesn't go to the foreach loop so it will returns nothing

Comment: `files` won't be `null` because `GetFiles` doesen't return a `null` but, if it were, the code would fail as I describe. Try `foreach(var anything in null){}`.

Answer (score 1):

What if your `files` has no file?

Your code will skip `foreach` statement but it wouldn't return anything because out of your `foreach` statement, you don't have any `return` statement.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

foreach (string fileName in files)
{
    if (fileName == pcName)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false or true;
```

Or there is other `Linq` way to solve;

```
return Directory.GetFiles(usersFile)
                .Where(fileName => fileName == pcName)
                .Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
{
    return Directory
        .GetFiles(usersFile)
        .Any(fileName => fileName == pcName);
}
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, it does not really provide the OP with any intuition on why he is experiencing it in the first place. As such, it's not a very good answer.

Comment: @AntP: the first place, don't create the problem, and there will be nothing to solve.

Comment: But there *is* a problem to solve and simply posting a snippet of code for which it doesn't occur doesn't help anyone learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your array of 'files' could be empty.  If that is the case, you the boolean return statements would never be hit.  Put a final 'return false;' after the for...each loop and you won't get any more errors.

That being said, your fundamental logic is flawed.  By returning false in your else statement, the loop will never continue (assuming there is more than one file).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, why use [`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)? Use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead.

```
bool UserExists(string pcName)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(this.usersFile).FirstOrDefault(f => f == pcName);
}
```

This code achieves the functionality equivalent to your code.

However, you may actually want,

```
bool UserExists(string pcName)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(this.usersFile).Any(f => f == pcName);
}
```

Enumeration will begin immediately without the needless creation of an intermediate array. If a match is found early needless processing and reading from disk will be avoided.

---

You can avoid your "Not all code paths return a value" message by doing

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

    return files.Length > 0 && files[0] == pcName;
}
```

if you want to check only the first file. This handles the case where `files` is empty. Although, I suspect you actually want,

```
bool userExists(string pcName)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(usersFile);

    foreach (string fileName in files)
    {
        if (fileName == pcName)
        {
            return true;
        }            
    }

    return false;
}
```

to check for any file.